# Rest APIs for Content Search in Security and Compliance - Office 365

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, o365security-compliance

For an internal project, I need to make search for emails across the mail exchange server (Office 365). As we have content search in Security and Compliance in Office 365. I am not able to find relevant apis to implement the same.
Can anyone help me with this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/content-search?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 2):

The compliance APIs are not available on Microsoft Graph yet. There is a UserVoice request if you'd like to vote this up https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39920074-securiyt-and-compliance-center-api

Comment: JeremyThake is correct - no graph support for search and purge as yet (as of Jun2022)...need to use the old powershell method instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-for-and-delete-messages-in-your-organization?view=o365-worldwide

The uservoice link is no longer active. Microsoft is not interested in your voice.